# Opera buttons not working

Tags: opera

Opera 41.0.2353.69, Linux Mint 17 Rafaela

I've tried the Opera community but I've never had any luck there.

On some websites, buttons sometimes buttons don't work (or elements might be missing - eg tick boxes appear if I open the same page in Firefox).
I haven't managed to find out what triggers this.  If I copy the URL across to Firefox, they work.

JavaScript is enabled.
How to resolve.

Comment: Have you cleared temporary files or cache? Also, some sites only support certain browsers. Do you know for certain this site is supposed to work in Opera?

Comment: Before I wipe my browser of loads of stored passwords etc, what is the basis for this - how might it help/what specific problem might it solve? Thanks  Given that the sites include ebay & Western Union, I'd be surprised if they weren't built for Opera, which is now based on Chrome.

Comment: When buttons or other elements are missing in web pages, there is a chance there are temporary but incorrect versions of these in the local cache of the browser. Also, while I haven't worked with Opera in over a decade, all other modern main-stream browser I have worked with have the ability to delete temporary internet files without deleting the stored password, favorites, or other data it would be annoying to lose.